# Formalize as combinatorics problem (get all sets that boolean sum == (1,1,1))

Tags: combinatorics

I have such a problem: there are several boolean tupels (properties of some objects)

```
K1 = (0, 1, 0)
K2 = (1, 1, 0)
K3 = (1, 1, 0)
K4 = (0, 0, 1)
K5 = (0, 0, 1)
```

I need to get all possible combinations, such that boolean sum of elements == (1, 1, 1), e.g.

```
N = [(K1, K2, K4), (K1, K3, K4), (K1, K2, K5),
     (K1, K3, K5), (K2, K4), (K2, K5), (K3, K4), (K3, K5), ...,
     (K1, K2, K3, K4, K5)]
```

So the questions are:

1. Can be this problem formalized as combinatorics problem?
2. Are there any usefull functions in numpy, scipy (Python) to solve this problem?

I belive if I get formalization of this problem I'll be able to solve by programming.

Thank you very much for your attention!

Comment: I think that stackoverflow would be a better place for this question...

Comment: Why is `(K1,K2,K3,K4,K5)` not in your list of `N`?

Comment: Henry, sorry I didn't quite fully described problem. I want to have as little as possible of repetitive elements, that have 1 on same position.

Comment: Henry, sorry again!) I've decided that it's not so important to have lots of repetitive elements, couse their summed reliability (additional properties out of the question scope) will be lower anyway.

Comment: Belgi, I want to get some sort of formula that might be useful in math representation of algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a linear algebra problem than combinatorics.

Here $V=\mathrm{span}(K_1,K_2,\ldots,K_n)$ forms a subspace of the vector space $\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \cdots \mathbb{Z}_2$.  The size of $V$ is $2^r$, where $r$ is the [rank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_%28linear_algebra%29) of the matrix; in this case:
\[
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right).
\]

Every element in $V$ can be generated in the same number of ways (i.e. the same number of linear combinations of $\{K_1,K_2,\ldots,K_n\}$.  Thus:

> **Claim**: If $(1,1,\ldots,1) \in V$, then it can be generated in $2^n/2^r$ ways.  (Otherwise $0$ ways.)

You can find the solutions explicitly by solving the system of equations:

\[
\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3 \\
x_4 \\
x_5 \\
\end{array}
\right)=\left(
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
1 \\
1 \\
\end{array}
\right).
\]
You'll end up with some free variables (which may take either value $0$ or $1$), and the remaining variables will be determined from them.

There's a gazillion linear algebra packages out there, or you could write your own for this specialised problem (I'll leave that to you).